# Не отрабатывает gulp-less в связке с browser-sync с использованием @import

Tags: gulp, npm, less, импорт, browsersync

Имеется найстройка в gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp      = require('gulp'), // Подключаем Gulp
    less        = require('gulp-less'), //Подключаем less пакет,
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'), // Подключаем Browser Sync
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('less1', function(){ // Создаем таск less
    return gulp.src('less/**/*.less') // Берем источник
        .pipe(less([ path.join(__dirname, 'less') ])) // Преобразуем less в CSS посредством gulp-less
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку css
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})); // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { // Создаем таск browser-sync
    browserSync({ // Выполняем browserSync
        server: { // Определяем параметры сервера
            baseDir: '.' // Директория для сервера - .
        },
        notify: false // Отключаем уведомления
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['less1', 'browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('less/**/*.less', ['less1', browserSync.reload]); // Наблюдение за less файлами
    });
```

В папке /less имеются два файла. 
`style.less`:

```
@import url('but.less');

body{
    color: red;
}
```

и `but.less`:

```
.but{
    background-color: green;
}
```

при запуске `gulp watch`gulp-less собирает файл style.css корректно, подтягивая стили из `@import url('but.less');`, но при изменении в файле `but.less`при запущенном вотчере изменения из файла `but.less` не подтягиваются. При это вотчер видит изменения в `but.less`, запускает gulp-less и browser-sync, но gulp-less не применяет изменения из `but.less`. Если изменить файл `style.less`, то изменения применяются на лету корректно.

Пробовал имортировать but.less  с помощью `@import 'but.less';`. Безрезультатно.

Если прекратить работу вотчера и запустить его снова, то при первом проходе импорт подтягивается корректно.

```
+-- browser-sync@2.23.6
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- gulp-less@4.0.0
`-- path@0.12.7

λ npm -v
5.5.1
```

Win7 x64

Comment: Сам себе и отвечу. Судя по всему в версии gulp-less@4.0.0 бага. Я откатил версию до 3.5.0 и все работает. Подробнее можно почитать здесь - https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-less/issues/283

Comment: Ура! Я не один такой) Скорей всего ты прав, на счет багов. Вчера весь день разбирался , что не так. Аналогичная проблема была! Сегодня поставлю 3.5 надеюсь все корректно заработает.

Comment: да, это похоже проблема 4.0.0 либо там в комментах предлагают решение с использованием `gulp-multi-process` https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-less/issues/283#issuecomment-371123935 но я его не пробовала использовать